# Novella about a man stuck on a moon or small planet, in a facility run by extraterrestrials that resemble stalks of broccoli

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I'm looking for a novella I read years ago about a man stuck on a moon or small planet, in a facility run by extraterrestrials that resemble stalks of broccoli. The name of the moon, planet or facility is something like "Stukhir" (maybe misspelled). Two extraterrestrials make a deal with him that entails his being part of an experiment. In the experiment his brain hemispheres are shut off and turned on alternately at an increasingly rapid pace until he no longer can tell the difference from before.

I recall the first page including something like "A haze of tiny insects was drifting across the site." (This is a paraphrase.)

This story appeared in a magazine I no longer have and I think it was *Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine*, *Analog Science Fiction/Science Fact* or *The Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction*, in the 1980s or 1990s.

Comment: "Sentient broccoli" somewhat describes the Kanten in Brin's *Sundiver* and *Startide Rising*, but I can't imagine them conducting an experiment like that.

Answer (score 8):

Holy cow, it’s not just your memory talking: the aliens really are described as *“[resembling] stalks of broccoli”.*

> It might as well have been an exotic plant for all the life it showed. Its head was like a giant broccoli sprout, with eyes looking in all directions.

And the human colony is on Stukhir, not misspelled.

> The human colony on Stukhir wanted to contact another human presence, or make their existence known.

And it exactly says

> A haze of tiny insects was passing over the site like a fog — harmless, but it made Owen and the other human workers put on their face masks.

The short story is
["One Hand Clapping" by Steve Martinez](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41719)

Even if you’d remembered the title, a search engine gets you Zen stories and movies and blogs and blurbs, and even on ISFDB there are six shortfictions and novels with that title.

The Nmeri say wise factual things and are called Seers and have a shaman, but --- the people in the colony are descendants of human clones the Nmeri made, and keep for experiments.

And indeed *"In the experiment his brain hemispheres *are* shut off and turned on alternately at an increasingly rapid pace until he no longer can tell the difference from before."*

> The change came faster and faster, and reached into his mind—one half of him realized that the two lobes of his brain were being alternately turned off and on, but the other half of him had no words for what was happening and was terrified. The vibration accelerated through him like a tuning fork driven into his spine.

*No* other story could be like this bizarre, grisly story including alien viewpoints of humans in all their awfulness, *aliens* in all their awfulness, life forms mind-melded with organic “computers”, singularities that stretch part of a person like spaghetti, even more disgusting-looking aliens, and a non-conclusive ending.

*"I think it was Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine, Analog Science Fiction/Science Fact"*

Yes indeed!

It's [archived](https://archive.org/details/asimovsv19n06199505/mode/2up?view=theater) in Asimov’s Science Fiction May 1995.